# Корень в слове цветами?

Tags: корень-слова

Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста, подскажите, как определить корень в слове цветами: цв, цве или цвет?
Спасибо

Comment: @Marishka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Для выделения корня надо подобрать однокоренные слова и выделить ту часть этих слов, которая встречается во всех словах: цвет, цветет, цветущий, цветок... Общая часть во всех этих словах - цвет... Это и есть корень.

Comment: Верно, а если подобрать такие слова, как: цвести, цвели, цвел?

Answer (score 1):

> Верно, а если подобрать такие слова, как: цвести, цвели, цвел?

Marishka, это прекрасный вопрос, на который обычно "не умеют" отвечать школьные учителя.
На самом деле во всех этих словах один и тот же корень, который за долгое время своего существования в языке просто немного видоизменился и стал немного разным в разных словах. Чтобы это понять и не ошибиться, т.е. подобрать "правильный" ряд однокоренных слов, нужно обладать некоторым опытом и чувствовать язык.

В нашем случае надо задать себе вопрос, а если Т или ЕТ часть корня, то что это тогда? Это не может быть ни суффиксом, ни чем иным (с этим вы наверняка сможете разобраться позже), о этому это именно часть корня. К сожалению, всего рассказать тут нельзя. В других подобных случаях могут быть другие трудности и другие приемы для их разрешения.

Будем надеяться, что к ЕГЭ вы с этим разберетесь.